# Fastest way to convert many columns from BST to UTC in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, utc

In our current database, we have several columns of type datetime that are populated with a default constraint of `GETDATE()`. `GATDATE()` populates the column with the system time taking into consideration BST (We're in UK).

I need a script that will convert all the columns from BST to UTC. I am a java dev, and I could come up with a crude method, but we have a short downtime window with which to apply the change so as optimised an approach as I can take is needed.

In this case, a faster, more convoluted method would win hands down over a clean or elegant solution (not that the two need to be mutually exclusive!).

Any suggestions on methodology, or of course implementable sql, would be very gratefully received!

(Obviously the constraints will also be changed to instead use `SYSUTCDATETIME()`